# I and Q components and the difference between QPSK and 4QAM

Tags: signal-analysis

Both 4QAM and QPSK apparently produce the same waveform, but are they the same mathematically?

In a QPSK constellation, are the mapping points at 45, 135, 225 and 315 degrees while the 4QAM is at 0, 90, 180 and 270?

I also struggle to understand the I/Q components of such a constellation diagram. What does "inphase" and "quadrature-phase" actually mean? Are they just another way to specify the real and imaginary part for this type of usage?

Comment: Both are the same. QPSK can be considered as a special case of QAM.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both QPSK and $4$-QAM constellations have signal points at $45, 135, 225$, and $315$ degrees (note typo in your question).  They arise from *amplitude modulation* (or, if
you prefer, *phase modulation*) of two carrier signals
(called the inphase and quadrature carriers) that are orthogonal (meaning that they
differ in phase by 90 degrees.  The canonical representation of a QPSK or $4$-QAM
signal during one symbol interval is
$$s(t) = (-1)^{b_I}\cos(2\pi f_c t) - (-1)^{b_Q}\sin(2\pi f_c t)$$
where $\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ and
$-\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ are the *inphase* and *quadrature* carrier signals at
frequency $f_c$ Hz
and $b_I, b_Q \in \{0,1\}$  are the two data bits (called the inphase
and quadrature data bits, naturally, since they are transmitted
on the inphase and quadrature carriers).  Notice that the 
inphase carrier $\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ has *amplitude* $+1$ or
$-1$ according as the inphase data bit has value $0$ or $1$, and
similarly the quadrature carrier $-\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ has *amplitude* $+1$ or
$-1$ according as the quadrature data bit has value $0$ or $1$.
Some people regard this as an inversion of the normal scheme
of things, didactically asserting
that positive amplitudes must be associated with $1$ data bits and
negative amplitudes with $0$ bits. But if we look at it from the
*phase* modulation perspective, a $0$ bit means that the carrier
($\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ or $-\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ as the case may be) is 
transmitted with *no change in phase* while a $1$ data bit creates
a change in phase (we will think of it as a phase *delay*)
of $180$ degrees or $\pi$ radians.  Indeed, another
way of expressing the QPSK/$4$-QAM signal is as
$$s(t) = \cos(2\pi f_c t - b_I\pi) - \sin(2\pi f_c t - b_Q\pi)$$
which makes the phase modulation viewpoint very clear. But,
regardless of which viewpoint we use, during a symbol interval,
the  QPSK/$4$-QAM signal is one of the following *four* signals:
$$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right),\\
\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{3\pi}{4}\right),\\
\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{5\pi}{4}\right),\\
\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{7\pi}{4}\right)$$
corresponding to $(b_I,b_Q) = (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$ respectively.

Note that the viewpoint taken here is of QPSK as consisting of
two BPSK signals on *phase-orthogonal carriers*. The demodulator
thus consists of two BPSK receivers (called the inphase branch
and quadrature branch, what else?).
An alternative view of QPSK as changing the phase
of a single carrier depending on a $4$-valued symbol is developed a little later.

---

The QPSK/$4$-QAM signal can also be expressed as
$$s(t) = \text{Re}\{B \exp(j2\pi f_c t)\} 
= \text{Re}\{[(-1)^{b_I}+j(-1)^{b_Q}] \exp(j2\pi f_c t)\}$$
where $B$ is the *complex-valued baseband symbol* taking on values
in $\{\pm 1 \pm j\}$ and which, when plotted on the complex plane,
gives constellation points distant $\sqrt{2}$ from the
origin and at  $45, 135, 225$, and $315$ degrees
corresponding to data bits $(b_I,b_Q) = (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$
respectively. Note that *complementary* bit pairs lie diagonally across the circle from each other so that *double bit errors* are less likely than single bit errors. Note also that the bits *naturally*
occur around the circle in Gray code *order*; there is no need to *massage* a given *data* bit pair $(d_I,d_Q)$ (say $(0,1)$) from "natural representation" (where it means the integer $2 = d_I+2d_Q$: $d_I$ is the LSB and $d_Q$ the MSB here) to "Gray code representation" $(b_I,b_Q) = (1,1)$ of the integer $2$ as some implementations seem to insist
on doing. Indeed, such massaging leads to *poorer* BER performance since the *decoded* $(\hat{b}_I,\hat{b}_Q)$ must be *ummassaged* at the receiver into the *decoded data* bits $(\hat{d}_I,\hat{d}_Q)$ making the *single* *channel*  bit error $$(b_I,b_Q) = (1,1) \to (\hat{b}_I,\hat{b}_Q) = (1,0)$$
into the *double* data bit error
$${(d_I,d_Q) = (0,1) \to (b_I,b_Q) = (1,1)\to (\hat{b}_I,\hat{b}_Q) = (1,0)}\to (\hat{d}_I,\hat{d}_Q) = (1,0).$$

---

If we *delay* the four possible signals exhibited above by $45$ degrees or
$\pi/4$ radians (subtract $\pi/4$ radians from the argument of the cosinusoid), we get
$$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\Rightarrow \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + 0\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t),\\ \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\Rightarrow \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + 1\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t),\\
\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{5\pi}{4}\right)
\Rightarrow \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + 2\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t) \\
\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{7\pi}{4}\right)\Rightarrow \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + 3\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t),\\$$
which give the four constellation points at $0,90,180,270$ degrees referred
to by the OP.  This form gives us another way of viewing QPSK signaling:
a single carrier signal whose phase takes on four values depending on
the input symbol which takes on values $\{0,1,2,3\}$. We express this in tabular form.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
(b_I,b_Q) & \text{normal value} ~k & \text{Gray code value} ~\ell & \text{signal as above} &\text{phase-modulated signal}\\
\hline
(0,0) & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t) 
& \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t - 0\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
(0,1) & 1 & 1 & \sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t) 
& \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t - 1\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
(1,1) & 3 & 2 & -\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t)
& \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t - 2\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
(1,0) & 2 & 3 & -\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t) 
& \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t - 3\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
That is, we can regard the QPSK modulator as having input
$(b_I,b_Q)$ that it regards as the *Gray code* representation
of the integer $\ell \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and produces the
output
$$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t - \ell\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$
In other words, the *phase* of carrier $\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ is
*modulated* (changed from $0$ to $\ell\frac{\pi}{2}$) in
response to the input $\ell$.

So how does this work in real life or MATLAB, whichever comes first?
If we define a QPSK signal as having value $\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t - \ell\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ where the value of $\ell$ is typed in as `0` or `1` or `2`
or `3`, we *will* get the QPSK signal described  above, but the
demodulator will produce the bit pair $(b_I, b_Q)$ and we must
remember that the output is $\ell$ in *Gray code* interpretation,
that is, the demodulator output will be $(1,1)$ if $\ell$ happened
to have value $2$, and interpreting output $(1,1)$ as $3$ is a *decoding*
error that is not generally discussed in textbooks!

Comment: This is the most incredible answer I have ever gotten at SE! Even though I see I have a lot to wrap my mind around, thank you very much! Amazing...

Comment: My hat's off to Dilip for his fantastic answer.  On a purely practical note however, if you were to write a receiver for 4QAM and QPSK, and you have to correct for an arbitrary phase offset, it should be clear that the physical layer receiver for one will work as a physical layer receiver for the other.  Also - again, not to diminish Dilip's answer, but the simplest explanation of how IQ can relate to real-valued samples is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3784668/1249075)

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate Excellent answer. Just one doubt, can i assume that QPSK can be achieved by two ways. First one being  just amplitude modulating and sending on I and Q channels or second way by only phase modulating the signal by -lpi/2 where l={0,1,2,3}. So you needn't do a combination of both amplitude and phase modulation. Am I right in believing that i need to do both amplitude and phase modulation together to achieve higher orders of QAM like 16-QAM and 64-QAM?

Comment: In practice, QPSK is almost universally achieved in just one way: antipodal BPSK on the I and Q carriers, and it results in 4-QAM.  You can view it as phase modulation if you like but antipodal BPSK is the same as $2$-PAM or amplitude modulation and nobody uses a general-purpose $M$-ary phase modulation circuit (or DSP software subroutine) with $M$ set to $2$ for this purpose.  In practice, $2^{2m}$-QAM is achieved by $2^m$-PAM on the I and Q carriers and no phase modulation is used. Note that for $m > 1$, the PAM cannot be viewed (except by extreme nitpickers) as phase modulation either.

Comment: @DilipSarwate So It means whatever QAM system we implement is basically amplitude modulation on two orthogonal carriers. But we always represent constellation diagrams in terms of phase separation like pi/2,pi/4 or pi/8 depending on order of QAM. Is that just equivalent representation of amplitude modulated signal in terms of phase modulation for better understanding?

Comment: @Talasila The A in QAM stands for _amplitude._

Comment: @DilipSarwate Fixing a typo three years later, that's dedication! Thank-you! :-)