# QPSK and OQPSK Modulation

Tags: modulation, qpsk

In QPSK, after splitting the odd and even bits into the I and Q channels, and then multiplying them with the sine and cosine function, what next am I suppose to do?

Do I rearrange them back into their odd and even positions?

Also, in OQPSK do I make the first bit of my Q array a dummy bit zero to represent the half symbol delay in the Q channel ?

Comment: Your first question "..what next I am suppose to do?" is answered in great detail [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6447/235), and no, you do not rearrange the bits in their odd and even positions: you _sum_ the results of the multiplications by the sine and cosine. A QPSK modulator accepts $2$ bits every $T$ seconds, and spits out a high frequency (phase-modulated) signal that lasts for a full $T$ seconds, **not** a cosine for $T/2$ seconds followed by a sine for the next $T/2$ seconds. With regard to your second question about the dummy bit, yes you insert a dummy bit

Comment: what dummy bit?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson If one assumes that an OQPSK signal begins _somewhere,_ say at $t = 0$ instead of being present from $-\infty$ onwards, then during the transmission of the very first data bit, there is no bit in the other branch because it has not entered the QPSK modulator as yet. Some people insert a dummy bit in the other branch so that from $t=0$ onwards there is a QPSK signal with phase being one of the 4 values instead of a BPSK signal for a brief period with phase _not_ being one of the 4 values.

Comment: @Dilip, i confess i still don't see it.  you turn the machine on, the bits start flowing in, the first two bits are grouped together into a "semi-nibble" or "crumb" or whatever becomes the QPSK symbol.  even though you can represent it sorta as a filter (and i have), the pump really does not need to be primed.  a "dummy bit" is something you would have to add to an odd number of bits, then you transmit the symbols, then the symbols are recovered in the receiver, then the receiver tosses the dummy bit.  but i don't see that here at all.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson In **OQPSK** with serial input, the first bit interval is $(0,T/2)$ and it modulates the cosine during $(0,T)$. The second bit comes in during $(T/2, T)$ and modulates the sine during $(T/2, 3T/2)$. The third bit comes in during $(T,3T/2)$ and modulates the cosine during $(T, 2T)$, and so on. In the _steady_ state, there are always two different bits modulating the cosine and sine. The question is **what modulates the sine during $(0,T/2)$?** It is a dummy bit, or the sine is suppressed.

Comment: okay, yes.  and that is consistent with my *DSP-based* analysis below.  using **my** semantic (i don't like thinking about $\cos(\omega_c t)$ and $\sin(\omega_c t)$ until i have an $i(t)$ and $q(t)$ that are formally reconstructed from $i[n]$ and $q[n]$), during sample $n=0$, there still exists $x[n-1]$ and $a[n-1]$ (which is, literally, $x[-1]$ and $a[-1]$).  and you don't have that in **non**-offset QPSK which is where i was basing my original thinking that, while the modulation schemes are different, i was thinking they were **logically** the same.  but they're not.

Answer (score 5):

This question seems to be based on several misconceptions.

In a QPSK modulator operating at a rate of $N$ baud, *two* bits enter the
modulator during each $T = N^{-1}$ second interval.  If the bits are
entering on a single wire (at a rate of $2N$ bits per second, the
QPSK modulator first *converts* this serial input
bit stream at $2N$ bits per second into two parallel bit streams at
$N$ bits per second. For example, alternate bits are steered to
alternate streams so that, *say,* all the odd-numbered bits
are in one stream and all the even-numbered bits are in the 
other stream.

In some cases, the bits entering the QPSK modulator
are already formatted into two parallel bit streams at $N$ bits per
second. One important and commonly observed arrangement of this type
is when a rate-$\frac12$ convolutional encoder precedes the QPSK modulator,
so that *information* bits enter the encoder serially
at rate $N$ bits per second, and the convolutional encoder spits out two 
*parallel* bit streams at $N$ bits per second.  However, regardless of
encoding or not, the bits that the QPSK
modulator uses are in two parallel streams that are *synchronous*
(that is, the bit transitions occur at the same times (once every
$T$ seconds) and in each
bit stream, the bit occupies the entire $T$ second interval.

As the OP's question says, the bits are modulated onto cosine and
sine carriers.  As discussed in more detail [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6447/235), if the bits in the two streams are denoted by $b_I$ and
$b_Q$, then the corresponding signals, **say, over the interval
$[0,T)$** can be taken to be 
$$(-1)^{b_I}\cos(2\pi f_c t) ~~ \text{and}~~ -(-1)^{b_Q}\sin(2\pi f_c t),
0 \leq t < T. \tag{1}$$
(Ignore the negative sign on the $\sin$, it is there to simplify
notation in more detailed analyses).  The QPSK signal is the **sum**
$$(-1)^{b_I}\cos(2\pi f_c t) -(-1)^{b_Q}\sin(2\pi f_c t),
0 \leq t \leq T. \tag{2}$$
**It is not the case, as the OP seems to think** that the two
signals are separated into even and odd bits, so that
$(-1)^{b_I}\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ lasts from $t=0$ to $t=T/2$ and
$-(-1)^{b_Q}\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ from $t=T/2$ to $t=T$: the
cosine and sine signals last for the full $T$-second duration
and the bits $b_I$ and $b_Q$ both affect the signal phase for all
$T$ seconds.

Offset QPSK *also* converts the serial bit stream into
two parallel bit streams in which the bit intervals are
of duration $T$ on each wire, but the bit *transitions*
are **not synchronous** but occur with an *offset* of
$T/2$ seconds.  Thus, $b_I$ modulates the cosine carrier
to produce 
$$(-1)^{b_I}\cos(2\pi f_c t), 0 \leq t < T$$
but $b_Q$ modulates the sine carrier to produce
$$-(-1)^{b_Q}\sin(2\pi f_c t), \frac{T}{2} \leq t < \frac{3T}{2}.$$
The modulator output is *still* the sum of the two sinusoids,
but the sinusoids change phase at different times. In fact,
the signal can be deemed to be a $2N$ baud signal since the
phase can change once every $T/2 = (2N)^{-1}$ seconds.
Each bit still affects the phase for $T$ seconds, but the
bit transitions are staggered.  In the receiver, integrations
(or matched filterings)
are carried out over (staggered) $T$-second intervals in the
two branches of the receiver, and the decision devices
spit out one bit every $T$ seconds but at staggered times.
It is easy to multiplex these decisions onto a single wire
that thus carries a bit stream at $2N$ bits per second,
just as the input to the QPSK modulator (if anyone still
remembers that far back in this answer) is a bit stream
on a single wire at $2N$ bits per second.

Comment: BTW, Dilip's "$T$ seconds" covers **two** sampling periods (like $n$ and $n+1$) in my analysis below (which is still not complete, but i think someone could commit an entire book or chapter of a book on QPSK and maybe a whole section on OQPSK).

Answer (score 2):

sure, in reception of QPSK, you receive bit pairs as they are transmitted, and detangle them in the reverse manner that they were grouped together.

what's really cool about OQPSK is that the order of the bits going in can **naturally** determine the order of bit changing in OQPSK.  in fact, it can be made into a DSP modulation system *without* the need for grouping bits together in pairs.

define the bitstream $a[n] \in \{0,1\}$, and the bipolar binary signal as:

$$ x[n] \ = \ (-1)^{a[n]} \ = \ 1  -  2 a[n]\ \in \ \{+1,-1\} $$

then define these two gating functions:

even samples:

$$ g[n] \ = \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 + (-1)^n \right) \ = \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 + e^{j \pi n} \right) \ = \ \begin{cases}
1, & n\text{ even} \\
0, & n\text{ odd}
\end{cases} $$

odd samples:

$$  1 - g[n] \ = \ g[n-1] \ = \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 - (-1)^n \right) \ = \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 - e^{j \pi n} \right) \ = \ \begin{cases}
0, & n\text{ even} \\
1, & n\text{ odd}
\end{cases} $$

the I/Q quadrature pair is:

$$      i[n]  \ = \     g[n] \ x[n] \ + \ (1-g[n]) \ x[n-1]  $$

$$      q[n]  \ = \ (1-g[n]) \ x[n] \ + \     g[n] \ x[n-1]  $$

note that $i[n+1]=i[n]=x[n]$ for even $n$ and $q[n+1]=q[n]=x[n]$ for odd $n$.  so for either $i[n]$ or $q[n]$, the bit rate is half the bit rate is for $a[n]$ or $x[n]$.  so the bandwidth needed for the analog reconstructed signals $i(t)$ and $q(t)$ need only be half of the bandwidth needed for the reconstruction of $x(t)$ from $x[n]$ is.

then the discrete-time OQPSK modulating signal is

$$ s[n] \ = \ i[n] \ + \ j \ q[n]  $$

returning to the real $i[n]$ and $q[n]$:

$$\begin{align}
i[n] \ & = \ g[n] \ x[n] \ + \ (1-g[n]) \ x[n-1] \\
       & = \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 + e^{j \pi n} \right) \ x[n] \ + \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 - e^{j \pi n} \right) \ x[n-1] \\
       & = \ \tfrac{1}{2} (x[n] + x[n-1]) \ + \ \tfrac{1}{2} e^{j \pi n} (x[n] - x[n-1]) \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
q[n] \ & = \ (1-g[n]) \ x[n] \ + \     g[n] \ x[n-1] \\
       & = \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 - e^{j \pi n} \right) \ x[n] \ + \ \tfrac{1}{2} \left(1 + e^{j \pi n} \right) \ x[n-1] \\
       & = \ \tfrac{1}{2} (x[n] + x[n-1]) \ - \ \tfrac{1}{2} e^{j \pi n} (x[n] - x[n-1]) \\
\end{align}$$

the OQPSK modulating signal is

$$\begin{align}
s[n] \ & = \ i[n] \ + \ j \ q[n] \\
& = \ \tfrac{1}{2} (x[n] + x[n-1]) \ + \ \tfrac{1}{2} e^{j \pi n} (x[n] - x[n-1]) \ + \ j \ \left( \tfrac{1}{2} (x[n] + x[n-1]) \ - \ \tfrac{1}{2} e^{j \pi n} (x[n] - x[n-1]) \right)  \\
& = \ \frac{1+j}{2} (x[n] + x[n-1]) \ + \ \frac{1-j}{2} e^{j \pi n} (x[n] - x[n-1]) \\
\end{align}$$

now compute the Discrete-time Fourier Transform (DTFT)

$$\begin{align}
S(\omega) \ & = \ \frac{1+j}{2} \left(X(\omega) + e^{-j\omega}X(\omega) \right) \ + \ \frac{1-j}{2}  \left(X(\omega-\pi) - e^{-j(\omega-\pi)}X(\omega-\pi) \right) \\
& = \ \frac{1+j}{2} X(\omega) \left(1 + e^{-j\omega} \right) \ + \ \frac{1-j}{2}  X(\omega-\pi) \left(1 - e^{-j(\omega-\pi)} \right) \\
& = \ \frac{1+j}{2} X(\omega) \left(1 + e^{-j\omega} \right) \ + \ \frac{1-j}{2}  X(\omega-\pi) \left(1 + e^{-j\omega} \right) \\
& = \ \frac{1 + e^{-j\omega}}{2} \Big( (1+j)X(\omega) \ + \ (1-j)X(\omega-\pi) \Big) \\
& = \ e^{-j\omega/2}\frac{e^{j\omega/2} + e^{-j\omega/2}}{2} \Big( (1+j)X(\omega) \ + \ (1-j)X(\omega-\pi) \Big) \\
& = \ e^{-j\omega/2} \ \cos(\omega/2) \ \Big( (1+j)X(\omega) \ + \ (1-j)X(\omega-\pi) \Big) \\
\end{align}$$

so the next question to ask is what does the spectrum of $X(\omega)$ look like for a bit stream $a[n]$ that looks like 00000000...? or 11111111...? or 01010101...? or 10101010...? or 00110011...? or 01100110...?  and then what is the spectrum of the quadrature modulating signal $S(\omega)$ with those same bit sequences for $a[n]$?

Comment: Life is so much easier if one does not insist that $0$ map into $-1$ and $1$ into $+1$. Try using the transformation $x \to (-1)^x$ for $x \in \{0,1\}$ to get a _much_ simpler system.

Comment: Dilip, i agree for the most part.  [like with maximum-length sequences](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/tutorials/a-little-mls-tutorial), when you compute autocorrelation of the bipolar binary signal, multiplication becomes XOR of the exponent.  we can do that here, too, but eventually i want to show something about spectrum and it's easier with the expression shown (like how do you compute the spectrum of $(-1)^{a[n]}$ when you know the spectrum of $a[n]$?), however it is the negative of $(-1)^{a[n]}$, so maybe i should flip the sign on $x[n]$.  i ain't done with this yet.