# Implementing OQPSK in Gnu Radio Companion

Tags: modulation, gnuradio

I am currently trying to realize this block diagram in Gnu Radio Companion:

[image: OQPSK modulation and demodulation]

Before using a file source block with the binary I want to send, I plan on just using a vector with an alternating 1,0 pattern (e.g., [1,0,1,0....])

From there for the Serial to Parallel piece which block would I use?  Does such a block exist; if so I am not able to find it.  The way I picture this is that the first bit would go to the I multiply portion and the next bit to the Q.

[1,0,1,0]   [1 -> I]    [0 -> Q]    [1 -> I]    [0 -> Q]

Is that the right understanding?

Or would it be that, let's say 8 bits were transmitted at the same time to I and Q simultaneously and the Q branch would be on a delay?

Edit:
I think that I don't need to do that serial to parallel at all.

Current setup:
[image]

[image]

Something might be a little off though

[image]

Comment: I believe that with Offset QPSK, that the T/2 delay is **naturally** implemented by picking out the even-indexed bits and routing those to the in-phase (I) component and routing the odd-indexed bits (which are delayed by T/2, compared to the even bits) to the quadrature (Q) component.  so it's a demultiplexing operation, no need to do "serial-to-parallel" and then apply T/2.  I think your understanding is right.

Comment: I edited the comment above.  I think it is possible just to multiplex but I still think I have something slightly off.

Comment: I am no QPSK expert, but i have recently been [thinking out loud about Offset QPSK, which I think is elegant](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13987/qpsk-and-oqpsk-modulation/13988#13988) .  [another](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/processing-obpsk-as-oqpsk/26580#26580) and [another](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44827/how-can-i-generate-offset-qpsk-symbols-from-qpsk-symbols/44849#44849).