# Q and I part in QAM

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, ofdm, decomposition

I have one confusion in QAM about in-phase I and quadrature Q part, i.e. do they transmit identical data or not? For e.g. if i have 11001001 as a byte to be transferred, so will 4-QAM separate it like?

I 01 00

Q 10 11

or both I and Q are similar at any instant of time?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both the I and Q parts carry only one bit at any time, and a total of two bits are carried by the 4-QAM signal during each signaling interval. The data bits in the two parts (during a signaling interval) might *happen* to have the same *value* (both $0$ or both $1$) or they might *happen* to have *different* values (one of the bits is $0$ and the other is $1$.

For a lot of detail about how all this happens, read [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6447/235) that I wrote some time ago..

Comment: Thanks Dilip, so Q and I are two different information bits but not the same information bit. Also, the post shared is very very helpful, cleared lots of other doubts on QAM. :)