# Scatter Plot of OQPSK

Tags: matlab, qpsk

Below is my MATLAB code for OQPSK communication:

```
    data_in = [ 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 0 2 0 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 0 3 1 3  3 0 2 1 ];
    data_modualted=oqpskmod(data_in);
    filtmsg = filter(H,1,data_modualted); % Introduce channel distortion.
    eq1 = lineareq(nweigth,normlms(StepSize)); % Create an equalizer object. eq1.SigConst=oqpskmod(0:3);
    [symbolest,filtmsg_eq] = equalize(eq1,filtmsg,data_modualted(1:trainlen)); % Equalize.
    %%Scatter plot
    h = scatterplot(filtmsg,4,0,'g.');
    hold on ;
    scatterplot(symbolest,4,0,'kx',h);
    scatterplot(eq1.SigConst,1,0,'r*',h);
    legend('Filtered signal','Equalized signal','Ideal signalconstellation')
```

I am unable to understand which values to use to generate the phase
constellation diagram for my code?  How can i generate the correct
phase constellation diagram?

---

The first figure is constellation diagram of The filtered signal and the second is the constellation diagram of The Equalized signal

[image: The filtered signal]

[image: The Equalized signal]

Comment: If you're willing to do this without toolboxes, I recommend reading 'Digital signal processing in modern communications systems' by A. Schwarzinger.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to plot your signal's imaginary and real (I and Q) part at the exact symbol time – in other words, you'll need timing recovery to get the constellation from a time signal.

Timing recovery is among the more complicated things you'll need to implement for a receiver, depending on the actual kind of transmission you're dealing with.

Assuming you weren't aware of that, you might want to  look into these terms (I think the order makes sense, didactically):

- pulse shaping filter
- eye diagram
- Nyquist ISI criteria
- timing recovery

  - square timing recovery
  - Gardner timing recovery
- phase error correction

  - Costas loop

Comment: thanks alot @Marcus Müller 
but there is attenuation due to fading channel

Comment: so what? That's what you'd see in a constellation plot! (if the fading isn't too strong for the timing recovery to work; again, timing recovery is necessary for any constellation plot to make sense).

Comment: Thanks alot @Marcus Müller 
when i want to plot both the constellation diagram of filtered signal(filtmsg ) and the equalized signal(symbolest) on the same figure , the filtered signal is shown like  point.

Comment: so, is that a new thing? Can you mention that in your question please? Is that really about signal processing, or more of a "how do I debug my code" question (which would fit better on StackOverflow, for example)? Where's that plot in your question?

Comment: ya know Marcus, it seems to me that the best way to extract a clock out of the signal would be to use bookends in the OQPSK protocol of `1100110011001100` and `0110011001100110` (one would be the lowest frequency possible and the other is highest) and simply block any occurrence of `110011001100110` (15 bits) but inserting a `1` into the stream between the trailing `1` and `x` in `11001100110011x` independent of the value of bit `x`, and in the receiver removing the bit (which should be a `1` unless it's a bookend) that follows the 14 bits `11001100110011` from the stream.

Comment: [this is the analytic way i have been looking at OQPSK](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21866/processing-obpsk-as-oqpsk/26580#26580).  even though i have never worked on a project with it, this modulation technique sorta intrigues me because of its effectiveness (in doubling the bit rate and avoiding the higher bandwidth resulting from passing through $(0,0)$ in the ideal scatter plot and just moving in the circumference) and simplicity (it matches up to a serial protocol naturally). and you can see that `0011001100110011` and `011001100110110` move the spot around CW and CCW fastest.