# what is the difference between QPSK and 4QAM?

Tags: modulation, qpsk

i need to know the main difference between QPSK and 4QAM, i have searched over the internet and still i have not found a good explenation.

Comment: I vote to close this questions on the grounds that it is a duplicate of _[I and Q components and the difference between QPSK and 4QAM](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/6446/235)._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different types of QPSK: Offset (staggerd) QPSK, $\pi/4$-QPSK, etc.

In its most known form, QPSK is identical to $4$-QAM or $4$-PSK. That is, the same constellation can be referred to by different names. So there is no difference.

This constellation can be seen in the picture bellow (from Wikipedia)

[image]

Similarly, $2$-QAM is actually the same as BPSK, as is also pointed out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation#Rectangular_QAM).

Comment: you mean that there is no difference between them?

Comment: but when applied both of them for AWGN channel QPSK gives better BER values than 4QAM

Comment: If one is a subset of the other, the can be an optional difference.

Comment: @user24907 With equal parameters, their BER is also exactly the same.