# Some problem with the expression of QAM basis and signal

Tags: digital-communications, modulation

The expression of QAM basis is
\begin{align}
\psi_1&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{E_g}}g(t)\cos(2\pi ft)\\
\psi_2&= -\sqrt{\frac{2}{E_g}}g(t)\sin(2\pi ft)
\end{align}

- I want to ask why is $\psi_2= -\sqrt{\frac{2}{E_g}}g(t)\sin(2\pi ft)$,
  instead of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{E_g}}g(t)\sin(2\pi ft)$? Why is there a "-" (i.e. minus) before $\sqrt{\frac{2}{E_g}}$?
- And QAM signal is $\ s_m(t)=A_{mi}\sqrt{\frac{E_g}{2}}\psi_1 +A_{mq}\sqrt{\frac{E_g}{2}}\psi_2$, does the $\sqrt{\frac{E_g}{2}}$ here have a relation with its basis $\sqrt{\frac{2}{E_g}}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base choices are ambiguous. The $-$ is there because the author of the book you're reading decided it was better that way.

You'll probably find the cause for that in the *quadrature mixer* graphic that they use, where if the phase shift from $I$ to $Q$ is $+\frac\pi2$, since $\cos(x+\frac\pi2) = -\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

For a detailed explanation, see the first few paragraphs of [this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6447/235) from some time ago. It is, as Marcus Muller implies, a matter of convention, but in my opinion, having the $-$ sign makes for a cleaner and more consistent description of QAM than using the $+$ sign; YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked two questions.

(1) The reason behind a negative sign is to be consistent in dealing with real signals and their complex representation. In terms of complex signals, a complex data symbol is $a=\{a_I, a_Q\}$ while the carrier signal is $e^{j\omega t}$. During the upconversion process and ignoring the pulse shaped symbol stream (i.e., focusing on one symbol only),
$$a\cdot e^{j\omega t}=\{a_I+ja_Q\}\cdot\{\cos \omega t +j\sin \omega t\}\\
=a_I\cos \omega t -a_Q\sin \omega t+j(a_Q\cos\omega t +a_I\sin \omega t)$$

Obviously, it's just the real signal that is transmitted and hence for consistency $-\sin\omega t$ is used. On the Rx side, this signal is multiplied with $e^{-j\omega t}$ for downconversion which simply cancels the Tx carrier. In terms of real signals, multiplying with $\cos\omega t$ produces a DC term proportional to $a_I$ and multiplying this real signal with $-\sin \omega t$ produces a DC term proportional to $a_Q$ (and not $-a_Q$), the two minuses before $\sin$ thus cancel out.
$$(a_I\cos \omega t -a_Q\sin \omega t)(-\sin\omega t) = -\frac{a_I}{2}2\cos \omega t\cdot \sin \omega t+a_Q\sin^2\omega t\\
= -\frac{a_I}{2}\sin 2\omega t+\frac{a_Q}{2}t-\frac{a_Q}{2}\cos 2 \omega t$$
Filtering out the double frequency terms gives the correct sign for $a_Q$.

(2) Yes, the scaling factors in the basis functions are for normalization purposes. The factor $\sqrt{2}$ when appearing at both Tx and Rx becomes $2$ and restores the correct amplitude for $a_I$ and $a_Q$ (see answer to (1) above where a factor $2$ is there in the denominator). The same is true for the factor $\sqrt{E_g}$ as it eventually cancels out.