# difference between pi/4 qpsk and differential qpsk

Tags: digital-communications

What is the difference between a $\pi/4$-QPSK modulation and a QPSK differential modulation (DQPSK)?

Are these modulations identical?

Comment: They're not identical at all. The differential modulator has memory, the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

No, the modulations are not identical; they are quite different.

Differential QPSK uses one of 4 different signals
$$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right), ~ \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{3\pi}{4}\right), ~ \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{5\pi}{4}\right),
~\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{7\pi}{4}\right)$$

with phase angles $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4},$ and $\displaystyle \frac{7\pi}{4}$ to transmit two information bits, but the information is carried in the *change* of phase from the *previous* signaling interval, and not in the absolute value of the phase. That is, the information bits are $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$ according as the phase *changed* by $\displaystyle0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi,$ or $\displaystyle\frac{3\pi}{2}$ in comparison to the previous signaling interval. Note that it is possible to have *no* phase change or a phase change of $\pi$ (inversion of polarity of the signal) both of which can undesirable for different reasons.

In contrast, $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}$-QPSK uses the four signals shown above *and* the same signals shifted in phase by $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}$, namely, 
$$\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t), ~ -\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t), ~ 
-\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t),
~\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t)$$
but it uses them *in alternation:* in one signaling interval, the signal constellation is
$$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right), ~ \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{3\pi}{4}\right), ~ \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{5\pi}{4}\right),
~\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{7\pi}{4}\right)$$
and in the next signaling interval, the constellation is $$\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t), ~ -\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t), ~ 
-\sqrt{2}\cos(2\pi f_c t),
~\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi f_c t),$$ 
followed by $$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{\pi}{4}\right), ~ \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{3\pi}{4}\right), ~ \sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{5\pi}{4}\right),
~\sqrt{2}\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + \frac{7\pi}{4}\right)$$
again, and so on, switching back and forth between the two choices. Effectively, the overall constellation is that of $8$-PSK but only four points can be used during any given signaling interval.  Note that it is *guaranteed* that the phase will change at the transition from one signaling interval to the next, and also that the phase will not change by $\pi$ and so the undesirable phase transitions mentioned in differential QPSK (they also exist in plain vanilla QPSK) are avoided. Of course, the $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}$-QPSK receiver (and transmitter) is more complicated than a QPSK receiver or transmitter. Whether it is a case of
["What you gain on the swings, you lose on the roundabouts"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169213/15934) is something that needs to be considered carefully.

For the signals mentioned above, see also *[this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/6447/235).*