# From IQ to pi/4 DQPSK

Tags: digital-communications, demodulation, software-defined-radio

I need to decode $\frac\pi4$-DQPSK packets from an SDR, preferably in C#.

I have the SDR receiver part done. Now I'm trying to learn how to take the IQ stream and get the packet info from it.

I've gone through the math, but don't understand the notation. I've tried GNU Radio, but can't get blocks added on a windows machine. I can't find a library that I can get working. I know this is rather opened ended question, but can anyone steer me in a direction to do this? I've been programming for going on 42 years now, but this is my first foray into DSP, and at my age it doesn't come easy anymore.

If it helps any, I do know a lot about the packets I'm trying to grab. They are transmitted in pi/4 DQPSK at 16kbps or 32kbps (there are two packet types), with a preamble of f337eeb637660672. The packet format is known to me, and is not encrypted.  This is for a project that will be released for free, which combined with my being retired hampers any ability to pay for professional help.

Comment: Can you decode DQPSK packets?  $\pi/4$-DQPSK is more complicated since there are two different QPSK constellations involved. (see [this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/49170/235) for some details) and the receiver is accordingly more complicated.

Comment: You are most likely missing adequate DSP and communications system background and education to get this done on your own in any reasonable amount of time.  Tell your employer assign a DSP/Comms engineer to develop a prototype receiver design in MatLab or Python, and you provide the IQ data file to him.  You can then convert his prototype processing to a sample stream processing application in C# or something else.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I've seen that answer of yours. As a matter of fact I printed it out and it's laying on my desk right beside my keyboard. That answer alone convinced me to go ahead and ask for help on here. Anyone who could put an answer like that on a public board shows people DO care about helping others learn. I just wish I could understand it better as far as putting it into use on my own. sigh.

Comment: @AndyWalls I am most definitely missing adequate DSP and communications system background and education. No question. But that can't stop me from trying. Alas, I'm retired, so no employer to get help from. I really, really wish there was.

Comment: @Dougmsbbs Ok, well in that case, I'm guessing you'll want to budget yourself about 9 months to a year to learn, develop prototypes of simpler systems (e.g. BPSK and straight QPSK), experiment, and then perfect a working implementation of your desired receiver.  A good paper by fred harris, which brings to the forefront topics that most books gloss over, is here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/278639495_Let's_Assume_the_System_Is_Synchronized

Answer (score 2):

The OP stated he was interested in $\pi/4$-DQPSK (not QPSK), so phase synchronization is presumably not an issue for him.

As far as the actual implementation is concerned, you'll save yourself some time if you become familiar with the bottom of pages 29 (symbol mapping) and 37 (differential detection) in [this student paper](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra341/spra341.pdf). Ignore all the old TI DSP-chip specific information and the information on pulse-shaping, which is already built into GNU Radio (if the OP is using that). There is also a reasonable description of a simple timing recovery algorithm. It is serviceable in some scenarios, but not others.

Comment: Pretty shameless of TI to slap their copyright and logos to the paper while disclaiming quality and accuracy. Good find, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to avoid naming confusion: I take it you get sample packets from your SDR – the fact that your $\frac\pi4$-QPSK communication might be packetized can't already be seen in these.

## Getting Started

As a software architect, I do believe that a lot of good things come from getting an overview, if possible something like a simplifying block diagram. That allows us to reason about what needs to be done. Same for other complex problems like yours!

I can't give you a full intro on how to write that receiver – to be honest, our students wouldn't be ready to do that after the digital comms basic course, and that's 4 hours a week of education for a semester and a three hour test. And that after uni has primed them with three semesters of math basically leading up to that lecture. You're approaching a complex problem, and I deeply respect the effort you're putting in!

I hope, however, that me giving your problem a bit of structure allows you to divide it down to chunks that you can approach individually, and then ask awesome, specific, questions on the way to a solution. Cheers!

### ASCII Block Diagram

So, the typical receiver architecture for a single-carrier transmission like yours does look something like the following

```
Electromagnetic
    Waves  +------------+  IQ samples        +-----------------+
    +----->+ SDR device +------------------->+ Synchronization |   · Frequency
           +------------+  (complex numbers  +--------+--------+   · Phase
                           representing the           |            · Timing
                           RF signal, but             |
                           shifted to 0 Hz)           |
                                                      |
                                                      |
                                                      |
    data   +-------------+                   +--------v--------+
    bits   | Channel     |                   | Constellation   |
   <-------+ Decoding    +<------------------+ de-mapping      |
           +-------------+                   +-----------------+

           The transmitter added              Converts points from
           error-correction bits              the complex plane back
           to the data bits.                  to the bits that
           Time for  us to  take              determined which points
           these,   and  correct              were sent – i.e. the
           the    errors    that              "inverse" of the pi/4-
           occurred.                          QPSK, if you will


SDR -IQ baseband samples-> Synchronization -> Constellation-Demapping -> Channel decoding -> data
```

So, your constellation is $\frac\pi4$-QPSK, so that's the kind of constellation that we need to revert to get the 2-bit groups back that were converted into the symbols.

To clarify: this isn't necessarily complete – I willfully neglected to add an *equalizer* to the system. I simply hope you don't need one. I can't tell however from your problem description. I also omitted things you'd typically find in textbook receiver diagrams like this one like the *matched filter* that matches the pulse shape, as that is often part of the timing synchronization algorithm, or the constellation de-mapping, depending on where you'd logically draw lines

### Synchronization

But first, there's "Synchronization"; what does that entail?

- Frequency synchronization: Since the transmitter doesn't share the same oscillator as the receiver, it's very likely they have a difference in frequency. So, what your transmitter put at some frequency ends up on that frequency plus a fixed offset. The receiver needs to estimate that offset and correct it.
- Phase synchronization: Don't know how deep into the channel theory you've got, but the channel simply rotates the complex numbers you sent – and by a random phase offset! So, we need to estimate this and correct it, which means "rotating it back". For QPSK that's relatively easy (see what Dilip linked to above), but for \$\frac\pi4$-QPSK not so much.
- Timing synchronization: So you send Symbol1, Symbol2 … and so on, and because physics, there's going to be some transition of signal from one symbol "instant" to the next. (We call the filter that defines that transition Pulse Shaping.) Your receiver needs to figure out exactly when to "look" at the signal to get the actual symbol value, and not just the transition between symbols.

Note that the order of synchronizations isn't defined generally; the order I picked here is what I consider to be "most textbook & most likely to be applicable to Doug's problem", but it depends.

### Constellation De-Mapping

Or Decider, or whatever. It decides on the bits that were sent.

So, you know now that your signal is

- exactly centered around 0Hz (freq. sync.),
- probably rotated like it was sent  (or just rotated by multiples of a
  quarter circle, so that the bits could be wrong that you get out, but
  you could trivially correct that later on by doing a Look Up in a
  table for all four possible rotations), (phase sync), and
- you know exactly when to sample the signal to get the actual symbol value.

Time to take that symbol value and get the bits out of it!

You've probably learned that a $\frac\pi4$-QPSK is just a QPSK constellation, just that every other symbol gets rotated by $\frac18$ of a full circle. So, what you need is something to take these constellation points (which represent the bits the transmitter sent) and convert them back to the two-bit-groups that were used to select which of the four points of the QPSK were sent.

### Channel Decoding

The problem here (as everywhere above and below) is that things are noisy – and that means that you don't actually receive what was sent, even if all the synchronization worked perfectly (it won't, ever, it's what drives us communication engineers mad). You get what was sent plus noise. Sometimes you'll make a wrong bit decision based on that. You can't avoid that. It's in communication technology's nature to be noisy.

Certainly something you'd do after you get bits out of your constellation de-mapper; use the forward error correction coding applied in the transmitter to get your original bits back. Sometimes, you'd not even know what your data and what your error correction bits were prior to decoding. Obviously, fully defined by the error correction code the transmitter used. If that is not known and things don't strikingly lot look like one of the "standard choices", then you've got to infer the coding method and the parameters – that can be extremely close to cryptanalysis!

### Framing

If your transmitter transmits in packets, you'll need some way to detect the start and end of these – but how to do that depends very much on the packets' format, and how much effort you want to put in, and how important it is to detect every packet vs not detecting noise that is not actually packets. Since the place where you put that can't be determined without that, it's not in the block diagram.

## Practicalities

You said you couldn't connect the blocks in GNU Radio – not quite sure whether that means you "mechanically" make the connections, or whether you don't know what to connect with which.

For the first problem: Try running a Virtual Machine (e.g. in [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org)) running a Linux system image that already contains GNU Radio. [My Image](http://marcus.hostalia.de/GNU_Radio-Live-uhd_and_gqrx.iso) might be what you'd like.

For the second problem: Maybe GNU Radio's [Guided Tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org) is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, Marcus. I printed this out, it now sits on my desk with Dilip's tour de force post.